# DriveApp fails to create folder named 'Test'

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have the following function to create a folder in Google Drive. For debugging purposes, I have assigned the name "Test" to reportsFolder. However, the folder is not created in Drive after running the function. I have confirmed that the folder does not exist in my Drive prior to running the function. If reportsFolder is assigned another name such as "test", the folder is created successfully.

Why does a folder named "Test" fail to be created but other folder names work as expected?

```
function createFolder() {
  var reportsFolder = "Test";
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(reportsFolder);
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    folder = folders.next();
    if (folder.getName() == reportsFolder) {
      return folder;
    }
  }
  return DriveApp.createFolder(reportsFolder);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

I ran testprev().

```
function createTestFolder() {
  var reportsFolder = "Test";
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(reportsFolder);
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    let folder = folders.next();
    if (folder.getName() == reportsFolder) {
      return folder;
    }
  }
  return DriveApp.createFolder(reportsFolder);
}

function testprev() {
  Logger.log(createTestFolder())
}

function getPathAllDrivesFromId(fileid) {
  var ids = [{id:fileid,name:DriveApp.getFileById(fileid).getName()}];
  let r;
  do {
    r = Drive.Files.get(fileid,{supportsAllDrives:true,supportsTeamDrives:true});
    if(r.parents.length > 0) {
      //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(r.parents[0]));
      ids.push({id:r.parents[0].id,name:DriveApp.getFolderById(r.parents[0].id).getName()});
      fileid = r.parents[0].id
    }
  }while (r.parents.length > 0);
  if(ids[ids.length - 1].name == "Drive") {
    ids[ids.length - 1].name = Drive.Drives.get(ids[ids.length - 1].id).name;
  }
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(ids));
  let path = ids.map(obj => obj.name).flat().reverse().join(' / ')
  //Logger.log(path);
  return path;
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper, was the folder created in Drive? Your function always appears to run correctly without error for me, but the folder is never actually created.

Comment: It is created in the root every time

Comment: Search for the folder name using GDrive and see if you if you already have one somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, I found the error, it was finding a subfolder many folders down named the same name. Is there a way to modify my function so it only scans the root and creates the folder in the root if it doesn't already exist in root?

Comment: You could look for a specific path